# Debugging a signed jar

Tags: java, debugging, web-applications, jar

Is there a way to debug a signed jar file? I built my applet Java file as a signed jar and use that built file in my main webapp. I tried debugging through my original file but none of the breakpoints work.

EDIT: I'm using Kepler and setting the breakpoints in Debug mode. I also have my weblogic server running in debug mode. The rest of my breakpoints in the server side code work fine, but the code for the signed jar doesn't.

Comment: Breakpoints aren't set in the code itself.  They are set in the debugger/IDE.  Are you trying to run the code outside the IDE and are expecting the breakpoints to stop execution?  That won't work.

Comment: Did you compile the classes with debugging flag set to add debugging information?

Comment: Sorry about that, I added my IDE above.

Comment: If the jar is really an applet, it's just another file served by your webapp, downloaded by the browser, and executed by the Java plugin on the client machine. Debugging the wab application will never allow you to debug the applet code: it's not executed in the server at all.

Comment: The fact that the Jar is signed has nothing to do with debugging it. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Although, I'm not 100% clear on your question I believe that once you have a jar you should switch your frame of mind to integration testing.

That being said, to debug and test your .jar I'd recommend writing unit test that call classes and functions in your jar to determine if they behave like you'd expect as opposed to setting break points, which won't work with a jar.

In this way you can debug your jar. If this is the right direction, let me know and I'll give you an example.

Comment: So then a JUnit test should work for the file right?

Comment: Given that I haven't seen it...yes. If you have a file that contains a class with a bunch of functions, you can create unit test with JUnit that call those functions and assert they behave how you expect. If they don't, then you need to keep coding until they do. @GetOtterHere

Comment: Ok I tested the file and it runs as expected. The problem I'm still running into (and not sure how to test) is a PrivilegedActionException when I call my function in one of my JavaScript files. Would this error be related to the fact that my jar is signed? The method in question creates a trayicon in the system tray, and I make sure to run doPrivileged at the start of the method if that helps